# Split Yaml configuration files in order to share sections with many Springboot instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am working on a project made of many Springboot microservices. Each microservice has its dedicated configuration file. However, in the configurations, there are **common parts** that I would like to externalize in order to **avoid duplications**

Let's take an example with two microservices, M1 and M2

M1's `application.yaml` is:

```yaml
specific: "M1 specific"
common:
  common1: "common parameter"
  common2: true
```

And M2's `application.yaml` is:

```yaml
specific: "M2 specific"
common:
  common1: "common parameter"
  common2: true
```

My objective would be that

- each microservice keep its own `application.yaml` containing only its specific configuration
- but each specific configuration file would reference the externalized YAML containing the common configuration

Doing so, my example would become:

For M1's `application.yaml`:

```yaml
specific: "M1 specific"
common-configuration: "/tmp/common.yaml"
```

For M2's `application.yaml`:

```yaml
specific: "M2 specific"
common-configuration: "/tmp/common.yaml"
```

And for the "externalized" configuration `/tmp/common.yaml`, something like

```yaml
common:
  common1: "common parameter"
  common2: true
```

Do you know if it is feasible?

- If it is, what would be the way to do it?
- If it is not, what would be an alternative solution?

Thanks for help

Comment: Put the common things in the regular `application.yml` and the specific ones in a profile specific file `application-M1.yml` then use the profiles to control which additional files to load (or use the `--spring.config.additional-location` to specify explicit files. Or put an `application.yml` next to the jar this will take precedence (for properties) over the one delivered by default.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar exercise couple of days ago. You need to put application.yml as the common configuration file which will be downloaded for each application's call to the config server. All the application specific configuration files should have the name identical to the `spring.application.name` property.

[Here](https://github.com/kdsalvy/Spring-Boot/tree/master/ConfigRepo) is the link to my config repo in git, for your reference.